# Chaining together several lists that consist of more lists

Tags: python, list

I'm currently working on a project for my Introduction to Computer Science lecture and now came across following problem: The Output of my Code are lists which contains lists and I would like to put all object from all those lists into one large list. The ourput looks like this:

```
[[['0452']], 
 [['1234'], ['176']], 
 [['2245'], ['2345', '2345'], ['2545']], 
 [['3452', '3432'], ['3523']],
 [['44563'], ['4523']],
 [['5234', '5234', '5234'], ['5435'], ['563']],
 [['6435']], 
 [['7134']],
 [['8324']], 
 ['923', '9936']
]
```

Comment: Can you post the code you've already written to try and accomplish this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to make a flat list out of list of lists?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/952914/how-to-make-a-flat-list-out-of-list-of-lists)

Comment: What is the issue, exactly? Can you be more specific?

Answer (score 1):

You can use recursion for this as not all sub lists are the same length:

```
def unpack(iterable):
    res = []
    for x in iterable:
      if isinstance(x, list):
          res.extend(unpack(x))
      else:
          res.append(x)
    return res
```

---

```
>>> data = data = [[['0452']], [['1234'], ['176']], [['2245'], ['2345', '2345'], ['2545']], [['3452', '3432'], ['3523']], [['44563'], ['4523']], [['5234', '5234', '5234'], ['5435'], ['563']], [['6435']], [['7134']], [['8324']], ['923', '9936']]
>>> unpack(data)
['0452', '1234', '176', '2245', '2345', '2345', '2545', '3452', '3432', '3523', '44563', '4523', '5234', '5234', '5234', '5435', '563', '6435', '7134', '8324', '923', '9936']
```

Answer (score 0):

```
big_list=[element for list_ in bigger_list for element in list_]
```

Comment: This does not get just a list of strings. It only partially unpacks the list.

Comment: Code-only answers are considered low quality: make sure to provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem.
It will help the asker and future readers both if you can add more information in your post. See also Explaining entirely code-based answers: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers

Answer (score 0):

here's the solution:

first convert your output to string then do as follows:

```
import re
text= "[['0452']], [['1234'], ['176']], [['2245'], ['2345', '2345'], ['2545']], [['3452', '3432'], ['3523']], [['44563'], ['4523']], [['5234', '5234', '5234'], ['5435'], ['563']], [['6435']], [['7134']], [['8324']], ['923', '9936']]" 
pattern = r'[^0-9]'
text = re.sub(pattern, '  ', text)
print(text)
```

result:

```
['0452', '1234', '176', '2245', '2345', '2345', '2545', '3452', '3432', '3523', '44563', '4523', '5234', '5234', '5234', '5435', '563', '6435', '7134', '8324', '923', '9936']
```